# Creating a list of numbers c#

Tags: c#, list, random

I've been looking around and trying to make this work but I think I'm too unexperienced and soon I've give up!
This is the beginning of my program:

```
       int ChosenRandom;


        Console.WriteLine("Choose how many random numbers yu want: ");     
        ChosenRandom = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                    //Input from user

        Random rnd = new Random(); 
        int RandomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 10);

        //Insert list

        Console.WriteLine("Random numbers: "+RandomNumber);
        RandomNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

After I've asked the user to choose how many random numbers he/she wants, I want the program to generate a list with those visible on the screen.So could someone help me and also explain how it's working so that I get it... and doesn't have to ask again =)

Thanks.

Comment: What about a [`for`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop?

Comment: Use a `for` loop to generate as many random numbers the user wants, store them in a `List`, in the loop you can also print each number. After a book / tutorial you should be able to do this.

Comment: Please go through a tutorial about C# on pluralsight and read a good book about C# and you will certainly know the answer!

Comment: I'd go with the for-loop or `Enumerable.Range(1,ChosenRandom).Select(i=>rnd.Next(0,10)).ToList()`

Comment: I find this somewhat difficult but I'm trying and learning. Thanks anyway for putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need a **for** loop to iterate from 0 to their number and print out a random number for each iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ChosenRandom; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(0,10));
}
```

I'd advise checking out [this](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/loops) tutorial on loops.

Comment: @Evelina, please can you mark this question as answered if this solves your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int ChosenRandom,i;

    Console.WriteLine("Choose how many random numbers you want: ");     
    ChosenRandom = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                   
    int[] data = new int[ChoseRandom];
    Random rnd = new Random(); 
    for(i=0;i<ChosenRandom ;i++)
    data[i] = rnd.Next(0, 10);

    for(i=0;i<ChosenRandom ;i++)
    Console.WriteLine("Random numbers:{0} ",a[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know how many numbers you want to create you can just use an array instead of your single Variable.

```
int[] randomNumbers = new int[ChoseRandom];
for(int i = 0; i < ChoseRandom; i++)
{
   randomNumbers[i] = rnd.Next(0, 10);
   Console.WriteLine("Random numbers: {0}", randomNumbers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Console.WriteLine("how many random numbers you want?");

         int num = 0;
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num);


        Random rand = new Random();

        int[] numList = new int [num];

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            numList[i] = rand.Next(0, 10);
        } 

        Console.WriteLine("\nRandom number : ");

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numList[i].ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```